# Moq, Method HttpClient.SendAsync is public. How to fix?

Tags: c#, httpclient, moq, automoq

I am getting the error:

> System.ArgumentException: Method HttpClient.SendAsync is public. Use strong-typed Expect overload instead:
> mock.Setup(x => x.SendAsync());

While trying to run the following code:

```
autoMock.Mock<HttpClient>()
        .Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
            "SendAsync",
            ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
            ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
        )
        .ReturnsAsync(httpResponseMessage)
        .Verifiable();
```

What may I be missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you need to mock the `HttpRequestHandler`:

(*You might need to pass `MockBehavior.Strict` to the `Mock<T>` ctor*)

```
var mockedHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
```

2. you need to create the expected response:

```
var expectedResponse = new HttpResponseMessage
{
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
    Content = new StringContent(@"..."),
};
```

3. you have to wire up things:

```
mockedHandler
   .Protected()
   .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
      "SendAsync",
      ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
      ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
   .ReturnsAsync(expectedResponse);
```

4. finally you should pass that `mockedHandler` when you instantiate the `HttpClient` instance

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handlerMock.Object);
```

---

It is worth to take look at the [MockHttp](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp) library, it makes your mocking lot easier.